# How to set headers for json web token in expressjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am working on mock authentication in nodeJs using express framework.I am using passport-jwt and jasonwebtoken for authentication. I created api and working well on postman.But I stuck on front end side I am not able to use protected api's on front end side.In postman i send token using headers and it works well.But it does not work on front end side.How to send token and verify from front end side??
My code is:

```
app.post("/login", function(req, res) {
  if(req.body.name && req.body.password){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var password = req.body.password;
  }

  var user = users[_.findIndex(users, {name: name})];
  if( ! user ){
    res.status(401).json({message:"no such user found"});
  }

  if(user.password === req.body.password) {

    var payload = {id: user.id};
    var token = jwt.sign(payload, jwtOptions.secretOrKey);
    res.json({message: "ok", token: token});
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({message:"passwords did not match"});
  }
});
```

and if token is valid this post method should redirect to this page

```
app.get("/secret", passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res){
        res.json("Success! You can not see this without a token");

  });
```

Comment: you are sending username and password in body or headers of the request... ?

Comment: in body and using body parser i fetch from there.

Comment: Is your issue resolved.. ?

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install cookie-parser

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser') 
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
var cookie = req.cookies.jwtToken;
if (!cookie) {
    res.cookie('jwtToken', theJwtTokenValue, 
             { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
} else {
    console.log('let's check that this is a valid cookie');
    // send cookie along to the validation functions...
}
next();
});
```

Comment: jwToken come from where??